# How to set a Json response in suave webpart

Tags: php, json, http, f#, suave

i'm begining with Suave and F#.
I'm trying to pass a json serialized object in my webpart to get it in my response.

In php i have this

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Content-Type, Accept');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*');
?>
{
 "player1Key":"hdegftzj25",
 "gameKey":"aegfhzkfszl74852"
}
```

and with this i get my json object, then i tried to do the same with Suave and Newtonsoft.Json

```
type gameCreate= {
    player1Key : string
    gameKey: string
}

let create= { player1Key = "BadBoys2"; gameKey = "zLUGgtrht4456" }

let json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(create)

//OK (acc |> Json.serialize |> Json.format )
let php =
request (fun r ->
    match r.queryParam "playerName" with
    | Choice1Of2 name ->  OK (movies |> Json.serialize(json) |> Json.format(json))
                        //|>  Response.response(Json.toJson(info))
                        //|>  OK
    | Choice2Of2 msg -> BAD_REQUEST msg)

let webPart = 
choose [
path "/" >=> (OK "Home")
path "/elm/api/create.php" >=> php
]

startWebServer defaultConfig webPart
```

So i can create and serialize a json object but i don't know how to pass it as http response in my web part and with the above code i keep on getting error on my expressions type in my let php

Comment: What error are you getting? I don't know what type `Json.format` is, or where you got it from, but you need to pass a string to `OK`.

Comment: Actually, the code you have in your `Choice1Of2` case looks very much off, for any sane implementation of `Json.serialize/format` I can think of.

Comment: And what is `movies`?  That isn't defined anywhere.

Comment: sorry i forgot to replace movies by "create".
I get Error tye Incompatibility. Expected (string -> WebPart) -> HttpContext -> 'a but get byte [] -> WebPart  type 'string -> WebPart' don't correspond to type 'byte []'

Comment: I followed a tutoriel on Suave https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/12/2016-12-31-suave/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you've pulled in a few Json serialization libraries too many - you seem to mix bits of Json.NET and Chiron (which is used in the tutorial), to no great effect...

Let's take a step back. Suave comes with its own Json serialization module, so you can get something working just by using that. Here's how it would look:

```
let php =
    request (fun r ->
        match r.queryParam "playerName" with
        | Choice1Of2 name ->  
            let json : string = 
                create
                // this comes from Suave.Json, gives you a byte array
                |> Json.toJson           
                // converts the byte array into a string
                |> System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString
            OK json
        | Choice2Of2 msg -> BAD_REQUEST msg)
```

Now, if you want, you can replace the `Json.toJson` call with either the Newtonsoft Json.NET or Chiron implementation (but hopefully not a mix of the two). As long as the types align, you should be fine.

For Chiron in particular, you're missing the `ToJson` static member on the type you want to serialize (this is something that your tutorial does mention). Json.NET has a generic serialize function that produces json corresponding to the record schema, so it's a bit easier to use out of the box, but also requires more work to customize the output if needed.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to return a HTTP 200 response with JSON and set HTTP headers in Suave, then you can use the `Writers.setHeader` function:

```
Writers.setHeader "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" "true" >=>
Writers.setHeader "Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Content-Type" "Accept" >=>
Writers.setHeader "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" >=>
Writers.setHeader "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "" >=>
Successful.OK (movies |> Json.serialize |> Json.format)
```

The whole thing is an expression that constructs a `WebPart` which you can then compose with other web parts using the functions provided by Suave. So if you wanted to pattern match before setting the headers, you'd use something like:

```
let php = request (fun r ->
  match r.queryParam "playerName" with
  | Choice1Of2 name ->  
      Writers.setHeader "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" "true" >=>
      Writers.setHeader "Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Content-Type" "Accept" >=>
      Writers.setHeader 
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" >=>
      Writers.setHeader "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "" >=>
      Successful.OK (movies |> Json.serialize |> Json.format)
  | Choice2Of2 msg -> BAD_REQUEST msg)
```

As you are setting the CORS headers, [this snippet might also help](http://www.fssnip.net/mL/title/CORS-response-with-Suave).

Comment: Yes, now i'm receiving my json data but it's look like this "{\"player1Key\":\"BadBoys2\",\"gameKey\":\"zLUGgtrht4456\"}"
and i don't want thoses backslashes. Any ideas?

Comment: `Writers.setHeader "Content-Type" "application/json; charset=UTF-8"` is a correct header.